# Why does BibTeX sometimes recognize "quoted" field entries and sometimes just {braced} entries?

Tags: bibtex

Consider the following BibTeX entry:

```
@article{kit11,
  author = "Kit",
  title = "My article",
  journal = "2011 Journal",
  year = "2011"}
```

BibTeX complains:

```
Warning--empty author in kit11
Warning--empty title in kit11
Warning--empty journal in kit11
Warning--empty year in kit11
```

So, I had to change the `"`quotes`"` to `{`braces`}`.

**But:**
I downloaded a citation from a journal web site and copied it verbatim to my `.bib` file. It used `"`quotes`"` and BibTeX didn't complain at all.

Why?

**UPDATE:**
Here's a [link from where I downloaded the citation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/B6V51-50DXD0B-1/2/560018fd26978c2cfb4506da1a04c2b2). I used the *Export citation* link near the top of the page, and chose BibTeX format.

Also, in TeXShop preferences, in the Source tab, in the Encoding section in the lower right, I see Unicode (UTF-8). Could this be the problem? What would be a wise setting for this if I frequently use BibTeX?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I started using BibDesk, and all those problems disappeared. To all who took the time to troubleshoot my problem, I appreciate the effort `:)`

Comment: Could you give an example of a citation that had quotes that works?

Comment: Quotes should work. I've just tried your example as the single bib entry in a file and it does work. Are you sure there are no other errors in the .bib file causing this?

Comment: @Juan: I'm not sure if there are other errors. I actually tried this with a lone entry. I'm using TeX Live 2010 in TeXShop.

Comment: Are you sure that the quotes are correct ASCII quotes? Sometimes if you copy stuff like BibTeX entries verbatim from a web browser the quotes are replaced by UNICODE quotes! Your example works fine on my machine.

Comment: @Martin: Do you mean that _typed_ double quotes and _copied from browser_ double quotes are different?

Comment: @Kit: the CMS might automatically translate "ASCII" to “typographic” quotes. Sometimes they are hard to distinguish. Could you post a link to the page where you got the entry code from?

Comment: @Kit: yes, most likely is a problem with the encoding of the quotes. Which editor are you using? try copy/pasting the code you posted here in a couple of editors and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Juan: I'm using TeXShop. I tried pasting my example code above, my downloaded citation, and typed a few quotes in TextEdit. I don't see any difference. See my edits to my question.

Comment: I have exported many references from ScienceDirect and never encountered problems (sometimes you have to make slight modifications to some of the fields, but the quotes are unproblematic).

Comment: @Kit: Sorry, I misread your question. Perhaps you should post the file with the 'bad' bib entry on the internet somewhere.

Comment: @Kit: yes, like Philipp said: there are "ASCII" to “typographic” quotes.
I downloaded the citation now and the quotes are ASCII. The file works with TeXLive2010 under Ubuntu Linux. Maybe TeXShop converts them somehow.